# Implementing a bindable object with dynamic properties

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, bindable

I am trying to make an object in C# that can be bound to a gridview. I have three objects to achieve this. EntryTable, EntryRow and EntryValue. An EntryTable contains a list of EntryRows and an EntryRow contains a list of EntryValues. An Entry value object consists of an attribute name and a value.

The data structure is as follows:

```
public class EntryTable 
{
    private List<EntryRow> _lERTable = null;
    ...

public class EntryRow
{
    private List<EntryValue> _lEVRow = null;
    ...

public class EntryValue
{
    private string _sFieldName;
    private string _sValue;
    ...
```

I am aware that bindable object by default will only bind to the top level visible properties. As a result I only see a list of the EntryRow object names like so:

```
-------------------------------------------
Norseman.CommandN.Data.CNStore.EntryRow    |
-------------------------------------------
Norseman.CommandN.Data.CNStore.EntryRow    |
------------------------------------------
```

My end goal is to be able to bind a populated EntryTable to a grid and have the EntryTable object recognize all of the attribute names in all of the EntryRows and display the data as a grid. **The catch is that not every EntryRow will have the same number of EntryValues.** For example, if I was storing employees, some employees may not have the manager attribute.

I wish to handle the data like so:

```
First Name |    Last Name  |     Position             |     Manager
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Andrew     |    Milton     |    Software Developer    |     null
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Barry      |   Singleton   |    Web Developer         |     Marcus Manicotti
```

I've considered entering my data into the traditional System.Data.DataTable model but I would prefer to implement my own object to avoid the overhead.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WinForms, you can implement [ITypedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.aspx) on the collection.  If you're using WPF, you can use [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) on each item.

Comment: Because my properties are actually strings within each EntryValue, I'm not sure how to implement ITypedList so that I can extract the property names from the _sFieldName field and the values from the _sValue field. I really appreciate the point in the right direction. It seems like I'm somewhat on track.

Comment: I think you're going to have to figure out what you want to use for property names no matter what...  Even if they are arbitrary ("Property1", "Property2", etc)

Comment: Thats the unfortunate part. My database backend is set up as an Entity, Attribute, Value schema so that I can apply any number of attributes to an entity. My goal is to get a system in place so that I can take a list of entities with any attributes and bind it to a grid and piece the data together to create a master list of everything.

Comment: If the attributes for a set of entities isn't explicit, you could just loop through the list of entities in the list and get all of the unique attributes.

Comment: Hmmm... I can easily create a list of unique fields. However, the documentation on how to implement the ITypedList seems to be a little spotty. Any ideas on how I would manually define these properties for my grid?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Once I found out what I was actually trying to accomplish I found an article:

http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/02/04/simulating-fields

That pretty much sums up what I was trying to do.

Thanks again!